# .htaccess, mod_rewrite and SSL subdomain redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

Just a small problem really thats doing my nut in.  Having enabled SSL on the server I've setup a .htaccess to do domain (retaining any query string/page selected) accross the redirect to ship all traffic off to https.

This works mostly with one exception

```
http://www.domain > https://www.domain   (Works)
https://www.domain                       (No redirect works)
http://domain     > http://www.domain    (no sub domain on initial request redirects to sub domain as SSL only covers the www. sub not *.domain)
https://domain    > http://domain        (fails doesn't prepend the www. sub domain if missing)
```

I'm fairly sure this is something blindingly simple I just can't for the life of me find it and its driving me nuts.

Current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#determine if page is supposed to be http
#if it has p=home or p=home1 or qqq=home in querystring
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=home1?|qqq=home)(&|$) [NC,OR]
#or if query string is empty
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
#set env var to 1
#RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]


#all pages that are supposed to be http redirected if https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L=301]

#all other pages are sent to https if not already so
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} !1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L=301]
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I also had this which handled the sub pages so if someone went to http://www.domain/index.php?p=about it would redirect to https://www.domain/index.php?p=about
Now my current htaccess doesn't deal with the query string redirectors at the moment but I'm focusing on the sub domain issue for now.

Previous .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    #all pages that are supposed to be http redirected if https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} 1
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L=301]

    #all other pages are sent to https if not already so
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} !1
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L=301]
```

Updated .htaccess using posted answer so far

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#determine if page is supposed to be http
#if it has p=home or p=home1 or qqq=home in querystring
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=home1?|qqq=home)(&|$) [NC,OR]
#or if query string is empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
#set env var to 1
RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} 1
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

#all other pages are sent to https if not already so with the
#host name set to www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} !=1
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Where are setting `IS_HTTP` to 1 since that part is commented in your code above?

Comment: there's 2 rewrite conditions that check for https but the actual setting is in the rule its self with a hardcoded http or https the thing in general works its just the final redirect to the subdomain of the https section totally.  there's also an issue of doing it like this isn't doing page specific carry overs but I can kinda deal with that later as thats a problem with the host cond regex. I'm thinking I need another https on block to do the redirect for sub domain on https incoming

Comment: Is it happening over your Intranet only? Since you cannot have an Internet domain with address like `http://domain` I mean you have to have at least one dot like `http://domain.com`

Comment: thats purely a placeholder for you as an example as I don't want to provide the real domain.  assume its a www.domain.com and a domain.com primary and sub

Comment: No I am not keen in knowing your real domain. But since you're dealing with  `^[^.]+\.[^.]+$` kind of regex its better to mask it with correct sets. Also I believe `domain.com` or `www.domain.com` both are primary domains while `sub.domain.com` and `www.sub.domain.com` should be sub domains. Let me know if my understanding is incorrect since my attempted solution will be based on this.

Comment: anything before a first . is a sub domain so a www is a sub domain the primary is only ever the name+tld part. so sub = www.domain.com primary = domain.com, sub also = mail.domain.com etc etc etc  The regex is a new addition for me if you see my previous redirector i don't use the regex's.  now the previous one did the query string retention but wouldn't redirect the non sub versions of the domain to https www. sub now you see where i'm getting stuck :)

Comment: Ok thanks for your response, let me make an attempt.

Comment: yeah anything even just suggestions to try would be great.  I'm no htaccess pro and there's so many different ways of doing things I'm not even sure that what I've got is a good basis (even though it partly works)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33563/discussion-between-anubhava-and-dave)

Comment: I am actually not able to understand the problem properly. You wrote: `http://www.domain > https://www.domain   (Works)` so it means its already working for a sub-domain. Also about that **Previous .htaccess**: Is that your complete existing .htaccess? I am baffled because that Previous .htaccess doesn't show IS_HTTP being set anywahere.

Comment: It doesn't need to be set strictly instead I have conditional checks for status RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} 1. The previous one works fine for redirecting www. to https://www. but it doesn't redirect just http://domain.com to https://www.domain.com so there's 2 alterations I need to make when redirecting the root.  I attempted to fix this by regexing it which worked for redirecting all nonhttps traffic to https however it doesn't work when going to https://domain.com as the cert isn't for the root only the sub so I need to redirect root to sub on https too

Comment: The other issue is that the regex'd version strips out any page requested or sub folder requested and so if you do http://www.domain.com/index.php?p=about it jsut redirects to https://www.domain.com/ and strips the page details which I also need to carry over.  The previous .htaccess correctly handles the query strings/subfolders etc but doesn't correct redirect the root domains to the www. sub domain

Comment: So your cert is only for `www.domain.com` is that correct?

Comment: yeah only for www.domain.com and i need basically all requests to both http and https (without the www) to  go to the https://www. version (whilst retaining any query string and sub folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#all the pages are sent to https if not already so with the
#host name set to www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ok I'll give it a test in a minute when I get chance I can't use the query string cond above though (thats why it was commented out in my initial post) because its a content management system so the p= bit is variable ie: impossible to list all the potential page names

Comment: ok your solution is 99% of the way there.  The only thing that doesn't work is if you go https://domain.com (without the www. sub) it doesn't redirect to the www. sub domain and instead firefox shows the trusted cert error/warning etc because the cert on that domain isn't for the primary domain its only for the sub domain.

Comment: Can you post your complete & latest .htaccess in your question (just mask your actual domain). Most likely there is some minor issue there.

Comment: there you go i commented out the query string cond for the p= bit as its not actually needed when using request_uri that deals with the query string for me

Comment: Ok this is the problem: `RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]` since this is unconditional so IS_HTTP is always set to 1. Which means only 1st rule ever gets executed. Pls understand IS_HTTP is a conditional variable and it needs some conditions to set. If you don't need these conditions then I guess you want all of your pages using HTTPS, is that right?

Comment: yup everything needs to be https there should be no http at all.  (your point is why I had it commented out in my very first post up)

Comment: Ok in that case codes needs to be simplified. See the edited code now.

Comment: Ok that behaves identically to before.  Everything works but if you go to https://domain.com it doesn't redirect to the www. version as it matches the "already ssl" so do nothing condition and doesn't perform the redirect

Comment: No I have `[OR]` condition now which wasn't there earlier. So now redirect to `https://www.domain.com` will happen if either HTTPS is off OR if host name doesn't start with `www`. Can you try in a different browser or clear the browser cache.

Comment: Ok tested in Firefox stable, Firefox beta, Chrome Stable, IE 10, Opera old, Opera new, safari.  the redirect on the `https://domain.com` isn't working to prepend the www. so there has to be a problem with the [OR] conditional though to me it looks fine (i am no pro though)

Comment: I have tested it multiple times before posting and tested again, it is all working. Let me add an explicit rule for this but looks like something else is also happening.

Comment: Added one explicit rule for `https://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com` try it now.

Comment: check the chat you linked previously its still not working but since we're both here at the moment chat will be better than comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33586/discussion-between-anubhava-and-dave)

Comment: OK we worked out the issue in chat turns out 99% of the problem is me being a cheapskate the htaccess posted above works fine thanks